# Border Radius in Google Chrome 8

Tags: google-chrome, css

I've noticed that Google Chrome 8 Accepts:

```
border-radius:5px;
```

compared to the previous

```
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
```

Since Google Chrome updates automatically, is it time to convert all my -webkit-border-radius rules to just border-radius? Or should i just add border-radius to my rules?

Also please take Safari, iPhone into consideration.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add. Safari still needs the -webkit version afaik. Plus, there are always those few with autoupdates turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably keep both for the time being, if you intend to support older versions of Safari (the current version also accepts `border-radius` without the prefix).